# Visual Studio 2010 property sheet inheritance

Tags: visual-studio-2010, include, vsprops

I am trying to move my c++ project setting into property sheets.  I use multiple third party libraries, but they are not used by all of the projects.
Is there any way to use property sheets to bring in settings specific to the third party library I need for each project (mainly include and library directories).  I would like to be able to do this at a project level rather than a global level so if I get a new library I can test it without breaking my normal development projects.

As an example:
Library1: needs include directory X:\Lib1\Include and lib directory X:\Lib1\Lib
Library2: needs include directory Y:\Lib2\Include and lib directory Y:\Lib2\Lib

I tried creating two property sheets, but it appears that as VS moves through the hierarchy, it just uses the newest version of the settings that it finds (according to that hierarchy).

Is there any way to configure these so the directories properties are cumulative?

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: I found the answer.  The key is to use the macro $(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)

Comment: Is it $(AdditionalIncludeDirectories) or %(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)? - notice the use of % instead of $

Answer (score 0):

Click the drop-down arrow on the right of the field, select 'Edit' Check the box "Inherit from parent or project defaults' and this will automatically add the neccessary macro (eg $(AdditionalIncludeDirectories), etc)